# Replace Menu Item with Logged in username

Tags: menus, navigation

I have a topnav menu item that current says "My Account", I would like to change it so that it functions as:

Welcome [Logged in Username]
-> My Account
-> Logout

Comment: What menu? What creates the menu?

Comment: The menu was created by appearance>menu

Comment: The theme is largely responsible for how those menus work. What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jQuery, but you'll need to find that menu item's class or ID.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
global $display_name;
get_currentuserinfo();
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.your-class a').text('<?php echo $display_name;?>');
});
</script>
```